# Add link to image to provide an anchor/ref point in markdown

Tags: markdown, pelican

To refer to a header one can use in config :

```
'markdown.extensions.toc': {'permalink': ''}
```

but how to provide a dedicated ID based image internal for pelican blog link for an image to refer to the image from within text?

> eg. please refer Figure 1 # where "Figure 1" is a link to an image within blog

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python-Markdown's [Attribute List](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/attr_list.html) Extension.

First, enable the extension in your Pelican config file:

```
'markdown.extensions.attr_list': {}
```

With the Attribute List extension, you can define any attributes you want on any inline item by adding an attribute list immediately following the item. So, for an image do:

```
![some image](image.jpg){ #image_id }
```

Then, elsewhere in the document, you can link to that image:

```
[link to image](#image_id)
```

Just be aware that Attribute Lists are a non-standard Markdown feature which is only supported by a few Markdown implementations. Therefore, its not likely to work if you try to use it elsewhere. However, what does work everywhere is raw HTML. Simply define your image as raw HTML:

```
<img alt="some image" id="image_id" src="image.jpg" />
```

Note that the id is defined with `id="image_id"`. You can link to that the same way as demonstrated above.

Comment: @Walan if I added the ext include image and put "Please refer [Figure 1](#image_id)" it doesn't seem to work. The img in html get the "id" property setup right but the reference is simply copied as a regular text.

Comment: No <a href... added to the img though.

Comment: @mCs I guess I don't understand what you want then. Could you edit your question to provide more detail?